# M2: how does adminhtml UI component XML work?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, forms, adminform

I was reading into how the [UI component](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-component.html) works using XML because I was looking for an alternative way to add a new field to an existing fieldset instead of doing a rewrite/preference. It appears that in M2, the `_prepareForm()` method sets the fieldset and fields as in M1, but there is also a UI component XML file that can add additional configuration.

For example, `Magento\Review\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Form::_prepareForm()` has (well, at least ***appears*** to be associated with) `vendor/magento/module-review/view/adminhtml/ui_component/review_listing.xml` for a bunch of additional things.

Questions:

1. However, this `review_listing.xml` does not seem to do anything to the review edit form. I tried removing it completely, changing labels in it, etc., but it affected neither the review edit nor new form in the admin. What is this file for?
2. I tried adding my own XML at `app/code/vendor/module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/review_form.xml`, but this file is not read at all, despite the [original document](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-component.html) saying it is read automatically by the UI reader. Doc says `component_instance_name.xml`; is this supposed to be a systematic name following some convention? There is no indication that it is supposed to be.